# How to move_uploaded_files in php to a customize location

Tags: php

i want to move_uploaded files a folder back in my server directory structure but doesn't seems to work here is my script

```
$filename='image.jpg';
$path="../folder".$filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uplogo"]["tmp_name"],$path))
    {
        echo "success";
}
```

the path    ../folder is not working and when i do    /folder it work so how can i mange my upload in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path="../folder/".$filename;
```

A forward slash was missing at the end of `folder`, which means it was trying to move the file to:

```
../folderimage.jpg
```

as opposed to:

```
../folder/image.jpg
```